# Preventing spam from php mail

Tags: email, phpmailer

I have made a new website for learning web development and I was taught to use the php mail function to send emails. When I use the following code in the headers to send an email to my gmail address:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <admin@myWebsite.com>' . "\r\n";
```

I noticed that the email has a question mark next to it and gmail says: "Gmail couldn't verify that myWebsite.com actually sent this message (and not a spammer)." Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

As for my second question; I noticed that when I changed the last line of the header to:

```
$headers .= 'From: <admin@someOtherWebsite.com>' . "\r\n";
```

The email still gets sent like it came from another person's domain. (Although with the same warning mentioned above). But if the header is changed to:

```
$headers .= 'From: <admin@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
```

Then no email is sent. So can someone tell me what is google doing to prevent others from using php mail to send fraudulent emails using their domain?

Answer (score 0):

Your mail server isn't configured as tight as it could be.

You should make sure that SPF records are set for your domain, that you have proper Reverse DNS for the name your mail server uses in its HELO statement, and set up and use SSL for SMTP (ESMTP), easy to do with a letsencrypt cert.